# Как заставить JavaScript дождаться ответа сервера?

Tags: javascript

Например есть такой код:

```
let translates = getTranslates()

async function getTranslates() {
    return await HTTP.get('api/translates').translates
}
    console.log(translates)

const languages = ['en', 'uk']
store.dispatch(initialize(languages, { defaultLanguage: 'en' }))

store.dispatch(addTranslation(translates))
```

в консоли выводится только промис, а переменную translates мне надо передать в функцию уже с результатом

Comment: можно написать `await translates` вместо `translates`, обернув весь код в `async` функцию

Comment: getTranslates это и есть такая обертка

Comment: в любом случае он не дожидается результата

Comment: diraria, вы мне предлагаете в качествве ответа ссылку на набор костылей, большая часть из которых или устарела или не может работать в принципе

Comment: извините пожалуйста, мне очень жаль что тот вопрос не подошёл, просто обычно дают ссылку на него

Comment: Вопрос как раз в том что тот вариант который описан в том вопросе не работает

Comment: @JonnyManowar, комментарии к ответам надо писать под ответами, а не под вопросом.

Answer (score 2):

```
(async function(){
    async function getTranslates() {
        return (await HTTP.get('api/translates')).translates
    }

    const translates = await getTranslates()
    console.log(translates)

    const languages = ['en', 'uk']
    store.dispatch(initialize(languages, { defaultLanguage: 'en' }))

    store.dispatch(addTranslation(translates))
})()
```

Comment: Darth нерабочий пример, TypeError: Object(...)(...) is not a function. Правильный ответ: async function getTranslates() {
    let response = await HTTP.get('/api/translates')
    return response.data.translates
}

async function initTranslates() {
    try {
        const translates = await getTranslates()
        const languages = ['en', 'uk']
        console.log(translates)
        store.dispatch(initialize(languages, {defaultLanguage: 'en'}))
        store.dispatch(addTranslation(translates))
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

initTranslates()

Comment: @JonnyManowar, ну скобки он пропустил. А `.data` у тебя в вопросе не было.